# Getting Text From Rich Edit Control

Tags: c++, mfc

this is a very general question.

I've implemented a basic text editor by following the instructions on this site:

http://aclacl.brinkster.net/MFC/ch12e.htm

I want to write a function in MyWordView.cpp that gets the text from the rich edit control and split each word into an array.

How would I go about this?

Comment: what's wrong with the answer you received on your other question? have you tried it?

Comment: I've tried several methods but none of them have worked. At the moment I'm trying to figure out how to get the handle for rich text control. I need it in order to try GetDlgItemText.

Comment: So you're still trying to solve the other question's problem, right? So why not continue there?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following method to get the selected text from rich edit control,

```
class CSampleRichEditCtrl : public CRichEditCtrl
{
    bool GetString(CString &a_String, CHARRANGE &a_SelectionRange);
};

bool CSampleRichEditCtrl::GetString(CString &a_String, CHARRANGE &a_SelectionRange)
{
    a_SelectionRange.cpMax = 0;
    a_SelectionRange.cpMin = 0;

    CHARRANGE aSelectedRange;
    CString aSelectedText;
    bool IsSelected(true);

    GetSel(aSelectedRange);
    int aMin(aSelectedRange.cpMin);
    int aMax(aSelectedRange.cpMax);
    int aDifference(aMax - aMin);
    if(aDifference == 0)
    {
        aDifference = GetTextLength();
        IsSelected = false;
    }

    LPTSTR aSelectedString = aSelectedText.GetBufferSetLength((aDifference + 1) * 2);
    aSelectedString[0] = NULL;
    if(IsSelected == true)
    {
        aSelectedText.ReleaseBuffer();
        GetSelText(aSelectedString);
    }
    else
    {
        GetWindowText(aSelectedString, (aDifference + 1) * 2);
        aSelectedText.ReleaseBuffer();
    }

    a_SelectionRange = aSelectedRange;
    a_String = aSelectedText;

    return IsSelected;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I understand correctly this just gets selected text....I need to get ALL the text from the rich edit control.